# imap_search "FROM" issue

Tags: imap, search

I tried to search by the following criteria:

```
imap_search($this->box, 'FROM "@avito.ru"');
```

And I faced with such problem:

```
2013/03/03 11:24:23 [error] 12481#0: *102 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Unknown: NOT IMPLEMENTED (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0" while reading upstream, client: 9*.2*6.1*9.18*, server: 1*6.1*.1*8.*3, request: "GET /testmail.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "r*****ger.ru"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is check whether it is an IMAP issue or a PHP issue. Try connecting to the IMAP server manually using telnet (or, if the server uses SSL and you're on Windows, something like my [IMAPTalk](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/comp/imaptalk.php) client will be necessary).

Login and select the folder (done automatically in IMAPTalk if you supply the credentials and folder name in the login window), and then enter your search command, such as:

```
01 SEARCH FROM "@avito.ru"
```

See what the response is. If you get an error at this point, you know it's a problem with the IMAP server.

I would also suggest trying the query without quotes, i.e.

```
01 SEARCH FROM @avito.ru
```

Comment: Yes! This is IMAP problem! I change to another mail provider and my script works fine! So, problem in [mail.ru](mail.ru) connection. How I can resolve it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's anything you can do from your end... you need to contact the people who maintain the IMAP server and ask them what's wrong with it.